# FusionChart Issue

Tags: ee1

Please find the below code for load fusionchart on my home page, here 'newurl' loading data.xml from fusionchart folder. This works fine and showing graph, but my issue that, i m trying to load xml page from 'templates->data->data.xml'

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

  var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Column3D", 
                "myid here", "400", "300", "0" );
  //  var newurl =  "datatest.xml";
  var newurl =  "fusioncharts/data.xml";
  myChart.setDataURL(newurl);
  myChart.render("chartContainer");      

</script>
```

and the xml page (templates->data->data.xml )like ,

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="school" entry_id="{segment_3}" limit="1"}
{reverse_related_entries weblog="school_results" limit="1"}
    <graph bgAlpha='0,0' xAxisName='Parties (roll over the bars to see their names)' yAxisName='Seats' showNames='0' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0' outCnvBaseFontColor='ffffff' outCnvBaseFont='Verdana' outCnvBaseFontSize='12'>
{results}
{if segment_4}
    {if "{row_count}" <= "{segment_4}"}
        <set name='{name}' value='{content}' color='{colour}'/>
    {/if}
{if:else}
    <set name='{name}' value='{content}' color='{colour}'/>
{/if}
{/results}
</graph>
{/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

How can call this , i mean how can call the template file to script?

Answer (score 1):

Your data source needs to be a template you've created inside EE, it needs to be set as an XML template type, and it needs to know what entry to load.

So following your example, create a template group called `data`, then inside that template group create a template also called `data`, and use the template code you posted.

Then you could use `data/data/{entry_id}` as the value for the `newurl` variable in your javascript.